# Particles utilizando qml

Tags: qt, qml, particles

me gustaría saber **cómo puedo hacer un sistema de partículas** utilizando **qml**.
Espero me puedan ayudar.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues bien, no solo averigüe como hacer un *sistema de partículas* si no que también les dejo el fragmento del código.
Podemos iniciar desde la documentación para irnos guiando:
[Using the Qt Quick Particle System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-effects-particles.html)
o bien, podemos hacer uso de uno de los tantos ejemplos que vienen en nuestro *fyleSystem:* "/opt/Qt5.9.0/Examples/Qt5.9/quick/particles/affectors"...

Yo por ejemplo inicié con el siguiente ejemplo sencillo (y muy básico) que genera mis partículas a través de una imagen...

Iniciamos por lo más importante que es la importación del módulo que corresponde a las **Partículas**:

```
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0
```

Posteriormente escribimos el siguiente código:

```
Rectangle {
    id: bg
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "black"

    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSys

    }

    Emitter {
        anchors.fill: parent
        system: particleSys
        ImageParticle {
            id: blip
            anchors.fill: parent
            system: particleSys
            source: "images/blueBlip.png"
            clip: true
        }
        lifeSpan: 6000
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver dentro de un *Rectangle* es donde mandaremos a mostrar a nuestras partículas.
El resto lo pueden ir viendo dentro de la [Documentación](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-effects-particles.html) que anexo al inicio y así no tengan dudas.
Espero les sirva.